# C# HashSet<T> read-only workaround

Tags: c#, list, hashset, generic-collections, readonly-collection

Here is this sample code:

```
static class Store
{
    private static List<String> strList = new List<string>();
    private static HashSet<String> strHashSet = new HashSet<string>();

    public static List<String> NormalList
    {
        get { return strList; }
    }

    public static HashSet<String> NormalHashSet
    {
        get { return strHashSet; }
    }

    public static IReadOnlyList<String> ReadonlyList
    {
        get { return (IReadOnlyList<String>)strList; }
    }

    public static IReadOnlyCollection<String> ReadonlyHashSet
    {
        get { return (IReadOnlyCollection<String>)strHashSet; }
    }

    public static IReadOnlyList<String> Real_ReadonlyList
    {
        get { return (IReadOnlyList<String>)strList.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public static IReadOnlyCollection<String> Real_ReadonlyHashSet
    {
        get
        {
            List<String> tmpList = new List<String>(strHashSet);
            return (IReadOnlyList<String>)(tmpList).AsReadOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a test code:

```
// normal behaviour
// you can modify the list and the hashset

Store.NormalList.Add("some string 1");

Store.NormalHashSet.Add("some string 1");

// tricky behaviour
// you can still modify the list and the hashset

((List<String>)Store.ReadonlyList).Add("some string 2");

((HashSet<String>)Store.ReadonlyHashSet).Add("some string 2");

// expected read-only behaviour
// you can NOT modify

// throws InvalidCastException
((List<String>)Store.Real_ReadonlyList).Add("some string 3");
// throws InvalidCastException
((HashSet<String>)Store.Real_ReadonlyHashSet).Add("some string 3");
```

My questions are these:
Is there a better solution for the "Real_ReadonlyHashSet" property?
Will Microsoft some day implement the "AsReadOnly" method to the HashSet<T>?

Comment: There's an [ImmutableHashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467171(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: It's also not that hard to just write it yourself: https://github.com/airbreather/AirBreather.Common/blob/aba09330ae3066cb46ad7e0ee963e00d27e63cb6/Source/AirBreather.Common/AirBreather.Common/Collections/ReadOnlySet.cs https://github.com/airbreather/AirBreather.Common/blob/aba09330ae3066cb46ad7e0ee963e00d27e63cb6/Source/AirBreather.Common/AirBreather.Common/Utilities/EnumerableUtility.cs#L47

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is [the entirety of the code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,251) of `.AsReadOnly()`

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<T> AsReadOnly() {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ReadOnlyCollection<T>>() != null);
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(this);
}
```

The first line is not even necessary if you are not using CodeContracts. However, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` only supports `IList<T>` which `HashSet<T>` does not support.

What I would do is make your own `ReadOnlySet<T>` class that takes in a `ISet<T>` and only passes through the read operations [like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` does internally](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/readonlycollection.cs).

**UPDATE:**
Here is a fully fleshed out `ReadOnlySet<T>` I quickly wrote up along with a extension method that adds a `.AsReadOnly()` on to anything that implements `ISet<T>`

```
public static class SetExtensionMethods
{
    public static ReadOnlySet<T> AsReadOnly<T>(this ISet<T> set)
    {
        return new ReadOnlySet<T>(set);
    }
}

public class ReadOnlySet<T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>, ISet<T>
{
    private readonly ISet<T> _set;
    public ReadOnlySet(ISet<T> set)
    {
        _set = set;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _set.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable) _set).GetEnumerator();
    }

    void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Set is a read only set.");
    }

    public void UnionWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Set is a read only set.");
    }

    public void IntersectWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Set is a read only set.");
    }

    public void ExceptWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Set is a read only set.");
    }

    public void SymmetricExceptWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Set is a read only set.");
    }

    public bool IsSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        return _set.IsSubsetOf(other);
    }

    public bool IsSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        return _set.IsSupersetOf(other);
    }

    public bool IsProperSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        return _set.IsProperSupersetOf(other);
    }

    public bool IsProperSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        return _set.IsProperSubsetOf(other);
    }

    public bool Overlaps(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        return _set.Overlaps(other);
    }

    public bool SetEquals(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        return _set.SetEquals(other);
    }

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Set is a read only set.");
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Set is a read only set.");
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _set.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _set.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Set is a read only set.");
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _set.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add an update for ImmutableHashSet? The comment below the Question is easily overlooked.

Comment: @webbertee The Immutable line of objects aren't the same as the ReadOnly line of objects. Immutable is for concurrency... I'm no expert here on this, but using one in place of the other *could* result in various problems, even if they are subtle.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from .NET 5, the [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) class now implements the [`IReadOnlySet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlyset-1) interface. There is no built-in `ReadOnlySet<T>` wrapper though, analogous to the existing [`ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlydictionary-2) class for dictionaries, but implementing one is trivial:

```
public class ReadOnlySet<T> : IReadOnlySet<T>
{
    private readonly ISet<T> _set;
    public ReadOnlySet(ISet<T> set) { ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(set); _set = set; }

    public int Count => _set.Count;
    public bool Contains(T item) => _set.Contains(item);
    public bool IsProperSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> other) => _set.IsProperSubsetOf(other);
    public bool IsProperSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T> other) => _set.IsProperSupersetOf(other);
    public bool IsSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> other) => _set.IsSubsetOf(other);
    public bool IsSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T> other) => _set.IsSupersetOf(other);
    public bool Overlaps(IEnumerable<T> other) => _set.Overlaps(other);
    public bool SetEquals(IEnumerable<T> other) => _set.SetEquals(other);
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _set.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

The upcoming .NET 7 will also feature a new [`AsReadOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.asreadonly) extension method for `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`s, so let's make one for `ISet<T>`s too:

```
public static ReadOnlySet<T> AsReadOnly<T>(this ISet<T> set) => new ReadOnlySet<T>(set);
```

Usage example:

```
HashSet<Item> items = new();
ReadOnlySet<Item> readOnlyItems = items.AsReadOnly();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own implementation of an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` that wraps an `IEnumerable<T>` and a count:

```
public sealed class ReadOnlyCollectionFromEnumerable<T>: IReadOnlyCollection<T>
{
    readonly IEnumerable<T> _data;

    public ReadOnlyCollectionFromEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> data, int count)
    {
        _data = data;
        Count = count;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count { get; }
}
```

Then you declare your `ReadonlyHashSet` property like this:

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<String> ReadonlyHashSet
{
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollectionFromEnumerable<string>(strHashSet, strHashSet.Count); }
}
```

I think that would solve the issue.

Comment: I think it would be better to pass in `ICollection<T>` that way you can pass along `.Contains(` which is the most powerful part of a HashSet.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was keeping the return type the same as in the OP - of course, `Contains()` isn't a member of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. I suppose the OP wanted to indicate that the value was read-only via the type rather than via a property (`IsReadOnly`)

Comment: Ah, I was going by `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` which [does pass it along](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132478(v=vs.110).aspx), not `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It is odd though, isn't it? Microsoft don't seem to be very consistent in this area...

Answer (score 1):

> HashSet implements the IReadOnlyCollection interface starting
>   with the .NET Framework 4.6; in previous versions of the .NET
>   Framework, the HashSet class did not implement this interface.

[Read in learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)

Comment: `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` does not expose a `Boolean Contains(T item)` method, however.

Comment: @Dai You're right, but current implementation Enumerable.Contains() extension method trying to cast type to ICollection and if successful calls Contains on ICollection (cast to ICollection succeeds because HashSet implements ICollection) - and the implementation of this method will be Contains in HashSet. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1365

Comment: @Dai, there is a better way now. [IReadOnlySet<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlyset-1) exists since .NET 5 an it has been immediately implemented by HashSet<T>.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Framework 4.6 release, the HashSet implements IReadOnlyCollection interface along with the ISet interface.   [link](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1362/hashset-csharp-with-examples)... 
It does seem to.

You could also do this but maybe take a performance hit:

```
var foo = (IReadOnlyCollection<string>) mySet.toList();
```